# res.send() sends Type Error: callback is not a function - although whole procedure runs correct (async.waterfall)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I'm writing a function for my Node.js server (using express as a framework, MongoDB as the database). I have to call two mongoose queries:

(1) Find data filtered by parameters of one collection

(2) Aggregate data of another collection (needs result from the first query because one attribute gets appended to these results)

I now use the *async.waterfall* a function that makes it possible to ensure that the second operation only gets triggered after the first one has finished.

**The variable *resultResponse* (at the end of my code snippet) has the right value when I run the function.**

The problem I am struggling with:

The server throws the error **TypeError: callback is not a function** for the first callback.
This type error is also the answer I receive via postman calling */getRoutes*.
So *res.send()* doesn't send the variable *resultResponse* back (which is correct), but the error.

Does anyone know, how I can solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
    let async = require('async');

    app.get('/getRoutes', function (req, res) {

    var param = req.query;
    let resultResponse;

    async.waterfall([
```

(1)

```
        function (param, callback) {
            let dataCallback;
            // first mongoose operation
            Route.find(param).lean().exec(function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                dataCallback = data;
            }
                .then(callback(null, dataCallback)));
        },
```

**TypeError: callback is not a function**

(2)

```
        function (aRoutes, callback) {
            let oRoutes = [];
            for (let i in aRoutes) {
            // second mongoose operation
                Rating.aggregate([{$match: {route: aRoutes[i]._id}}
                    , {
                        $group:
                            {_id: null, rating: {$avg: '$rating'}}
                    }
                ]).then(function (response) {
                    let oneRoute = aRoutes[i];
                    let avgRating = response[0].rating;
                    oneRoute.avg_rating = avgRating;

                    oRoutes.push(oneRoute);

                    if (i == (aRoutes.length - 1)) {
                        callback(null, oRoutes);
                    }
                });
            }
        }],
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resultResponse = result; //console.log -> right result here
    });

res.send(resultResponse); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function will be seeking `callback` function as the first parameter. Check [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) for more details. `param` is defined globally so you don't need to pass.

```
function (callback) {
  let dataCallback;
  // first mongoose operation
  Route.find(param).lean().exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    dataCallback = data;
 }).then(function(){
   callback(null, dataCallback);
 });
}
```

#### OR

Simply return `data` insteadof creating `undefined` object.

```
function (callback) {
  // first mongoose operation
  Route.find(param).lean().exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    return data;
 }).then(function(dataCallback){
   callback(null, dataCallback);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your hint solved my problem.

[When continuing I found `next()` what brought me to a different approach for this issue.]